# httplib.HTTPConnection timeout: connect vs other blocking calls

Tags: python, sockets, httplib, httplib2

I'm trying to use python's HTTPConnection to make some long running remote procedure calls (~30 seconds)

```
httplib.HTTPConnection(..., timeout=45)
```

solves this. However, it means that failed connection attempts will cause a painfully long wait. I can independently control the read and connect timeouts for a socket -- can I do this when using HTTPConnection?

Comment: Use `{ 'Connection' :'Keep-Alive'}` in the headers; you can declare what you like but in reality it will depend on the server, that's where the `keep-alive` timeouts are set.

Comment: It seems to be the client that's timing out the connection (since if I set a higher timeout when I create the HTTPConnection, it works).

Comment: It can be a temperamental thing, I have been using httplib for over 1 year now; I have resigned myself to the fact that, regardless of how the server deals with `keep-alive`, sometimes it just times out for no reason. You could try setting `keep-alive` and check the response.status of an empty request, and if the status is ok send the real request with your timeout=x, and since this will be sent with the same connection, this means less chance of a failure.

Comment: I'm not waiting to send a request. I do that immediately. I'm waiting to receive a response from a long (remotely executing) call. KeepAilive helps with the first case, not the second since the sever is blocking processing and cannot send a keep-ailive message.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are not waiting to send a request, but if you deal with the connection failure first, you wont have to wait, i.e. don't include the timeout parameter with the first request, something like the following:

```
    httplib.HTTPSConnection ('url' )
    headers ={'Connection' : 'Keep-Alive'}
    conn.request("request blank", headers) #dummy request to open a conn and keep it alive
    dummy_response = conn.getresponse()
    if dummmy_response == 200 or dummy_response == 201: #if ok, do work with conn
       conn.request("request real", timeout = 25)
    else: 
       reconnect.  #restart the dummy request
```

Just a suggestion, you can always bump the question or have it answered again.